# C++ exception specification - handling not valid exceptions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gcc, exception, exception-specification

What is the standard behavior in cases when function throws exception not in valid exception list ? For example when I run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void NotLegal() throw(char) {
    throw 42;
}

void myunexpected () {
  cout << "exception not in list\n";
  cin.get();
  exit(0);
}

int main()
{
    set_unexpected(myunexpected);

    try {
       NotLegal();
   }
   catch(...) {
       cout << "exception catched";
       cin.get();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

It behaves differently on GCC and Visual Studio C++ compilers:

- On VS 2010 not expected exception is catched in general exception handler.
- On GCC `unexpected()` handler function is called instead of catching exception.

Why is this difference ? Why MS C++ compiler doesn't calls `unexpected()` callback ?

Comment: did you try to change your example? Just to be sure that you will not get an automatic convertion between 42 and a char. Just try throw() instead of throw(char).

Comment: it's the same with empty exception list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7twc8dwy.aspx) for `set_unexpected` calls out this behaviour:

> ## Remarks
>
> ...
>
> The C++ Standard requires that `unexpected` is called when a function throws an exception that is not on its throw list. The current implementation does not support this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you compiled with the right flags? Visual Studio has a default of not turning on exception handling for some optimised release builds.

You want [/c and /EHsc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7twc8dwy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: The documentation you linked to says *The C++ Standard requires that unexpected is called when a function throws an exception that is not on its throw list. **The current implementation does not support this**.*

Comment: I suspect also that VS c++ didn't implemented that. Could you write this as separate answer ?